# Copying DEB file and install - Error

Tags: debian, debugging, debian-installer, deb

I build a deb file for Apache2 from its source, also I was able to install and run successfully in the machine which I used to compile. But when I copy(SCP) that deb file to another machine and installed, log directory (/CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs/var/log/) for apache2 is missing in the newly installed system.

in both cases, I installed using command `dpkg -i <deb file>`

Can someone say what will be the reason?

Compiler:

```
root@compiler:/build/result# cd /CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs/
root@compiler:/CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs# ls
usr  var
```

---

another machine :

```
root@ubuntu-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1:~# ls /CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs/
usr
root@ubuntu-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1:~#
```

As you can see the "var" directory is missing when installing the same deb file on another machine. I used following config to build deb file

```
    ./configure --enable-layout=Debian --prefix=/CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs --sysconfdir=/etc/apache2-cs --enable-rewrite=shared --enable-speling=shared --with-pcre --with-include-apr --with-include-aprutils --enable-load-all-modules --with-suexec-caller=cloudS-www --with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/apache2-cs/suexec.log --with-suexec-bin=/usr/lib/apache2-cs/suexec --with-suexec-docroot=/var/www --with-suexec-userdir=public_html --with-suexec-uidmin=100 --enable-suexec=shared --with-program-name=apache2-cs --enable-logio
make clean
make 
checkinstall --install=no --pakdir=/build/result/
```

Comment: in both cases, I installed using command dpkg -i <deb file>

Comment: Cross posted: [Why files are missing while installing deb file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262411/why-files-are-missing-while-installing-deb-file)